# Is there a way to offset or delay the li animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to offset the animation but it seems it is not working in my code or I just need to do it one by one. That will be hard if it is please help me. I used icons for my li. I a beginner please bare with me and please excuse my English. I don't how to use the first child etc.. Please some one teach me. I appreciate it thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```css
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -173px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}


li i {
  color: black;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.3);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000;
  animation: FadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }

  85% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.navbar-nav li {
  animation: my-animation 300ms ease-out;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a479f40ed.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Index.php" id="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'active';}?>">About<i class="far fa-user" id="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Resume.php" id="<?php if($page=='Resume'){echo 'active';}?>">Resume<i class="far fa-file" id="<?php if($page=='Resume'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Portfolio.php"id="<?php if($page=='Portfolio'){echo 'active';}?>">Portfolio<i class="fas fa-guitar" id="<?php if($page=='Portfolio'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Contact.php" id="<?php if($page=='Contact'){echo 'active';}?>">Contact<i class="far fa-address-card" id="<?php if($page=='Contact'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "offset the li animation"?

Comment: Something like delaying the animation 1st icon to last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reorganized your code and it was missing a few things.

- `.navbar-nav li` animation says my-animation, but I updated that to your animation name `FadeIn`.
- I added `i` to `.navbar-nav li:nth-child(1) i` so the animation runs on that element and not it's parent.

There may be a few other things but you were almost there.

```css
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -173px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}


li i {
  color: black;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.3);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000;
}

.navbar-nav li i {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: FadeIn 0.3s ease-out 0s forwards 1;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(1) i {
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2) i {
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.navbar-nav li:nth-child(3) i {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.navbar-nav li:nth-child(4) i {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }

  85% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5a479f40ed.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Index.php" id="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'active';}?>">About<i class="far fa-user" id="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Resume.php" id="<?php if($page=='Resume'){echo 'active';}?>">Resume<i class="far fa-file" id="<?php if($page=='Resume'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Portfolio.php"id="<?php if($page=='Portfolio'){echo 'active';}?>">Portfolio<i class="fas fa-guitar" id="<?php if($page=='Portfolio'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="Contact.php" id="<?php if($page=='Contact'){echo 'active';}?>">Contact<i class="far fa-address-card" id="<?php if($page=='Contact'){echo 'active';}?>"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: Oh that's it I don't know that I have to put an I in the end thank you my friend! I'm sorry for the code I'm still not good at it.

Comment: No worries at all. You were calling the animation on the .navbar-nav li i, but then trying to adjust on .navbar-nav li, so faily close.